# How to store special characters in mysql using php?

Tags: php, android, json, unicode

I want to store special characters like **’**
in database.

I tried following code

```
$string = htmlentities($_REQUEST['string ']);
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['string ']);
```

But failed to store in MySQL Database.

MySQL Database is `utf-8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: i have set charset using mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8"); but still not working